# Problem installing Manim on Windows 11. Error regarding the wrong "decorator" version

Tags: installation, manim

I was following the steps on "Manual Installation"
[https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/windows.html#required-dependencies:~:text=Manual%20Installation%23](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/windows.html#required-dependencies:%7E:text=Manual%20Installation%23)

I installed this (recommended) version of ffmpeg https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-essentials.7z

And after running "python -m pip install manim" I got this error (after an apparently successful installation):

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
moviepy 1.0.3 requires decorator<5.0,>=4.0.2, but you have decorator 5.1.1 which is incompatible.

I was thinking about running "pip uninstall decorator 5.1.1" but I don't really know what I'm doing

Was I proceeding correctly?

If so, what exactly is the decorator I should install?